# React/Redux - Add element instead of replacing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using https://reactflow.dev/ library and in Redux state when I add a new element rather than add it to the array it replaces the previous item with a new one.
[image]

**Reducer**

```js
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  elements: [],
  currentElement: undefined,
};

const flow = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_ELEMENT:
      return {
        ...initialState,
        elements: initialState.elements.concat(action.payload),
        // elements: [...initialState.elements, action.payload],
      };
  }
}
```

**Action**

```js
import { ADD_ELEMENT } from './types';

export const addElement = (node) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_ELEMENT,
    payload: node,
  });
};
```

**DndFLow**

```js
const onDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const reactFlowBounds = reactFlowWrapper.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const type = event.dataTransfer.getData('application/reactflow');
    const position = reactFlowInstance.project({
      x: event.clientX - reactFlowBounds.left,
      y: event.clientY - reactFlowBounds.top,
    });

    const newNode = {
      id: getId(),
      type,
      position,
      data: { label: `${type}` },
    };

    addElement(newNode);
    setElements((es) => es.concat(newNode));
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `initialState` in the reducer, instead of the state.

Using the state might fix your issue:

```
const flow = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_ELEMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        elements: state.elements.concat(action.payload),
      };
  }
}
```

The `state = initialState` is correct since that means it will use the `initialState` by default if state doesn't have any value otherwise, but you shouldn't use the `initialState` beyond that, unless you want to reset your state to it.