# Redux - Array becomes empty after updating a single element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-state-management

I am trying to update a single element after filling its Modal form, but the state becomes empty, i.e rather than updating the element it deletes all elements.

I also asked another question and clarified what I want to do exactly, you can find it here
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69064392/edit

**BTW**, I am using Redux & [react-flow-renderer](https://reactflow.dev/) libraries.
**Reducer**

```js
import * as types from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  elements: []
};

const flow = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_ELEMENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        elements: state.elements.map((e) => {
          if (e.id === action.payload.id) {
            e = {
              ...e,
              options: action.payload.options,
            };
          }
          return e;
        }),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default flow;
```

**Action**

```js
import { UPDATE_ELEMENT } from './types';

export const updateElement = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_ELEMENT,
    payload: data,
  });
};
```

**Node modal**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { updateElement } from '../../../../redux/actions/flow';

const VPCNodeModal = (props, { updateElement }) => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    instance: '',
  });

  // options
  const { instance } = formData;

  const onFormChange = (e) =>
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmitForm = () => {
    const update = {
      id: selectedElement.id,
      options: formData,
    };

    updateElement(update);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal {...props}>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              onSubmitForm();
            }}
          >
            <label>
              <span> Instance name:</span>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='instance'
                value={instance}
                onChange={onFormChange}
              />
            </label>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
          </form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

VPCNodeModal.propTypes = {
  updateElement: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, { updateElement })(VPCNodeModal);
```

Comment: You pass null instead of mapStateToProps function.

Comment: Yes I'm passing null because I don't need to access the state object I just need the action 
 updateElement to dispatch it

Comment: Did you check the state with redux debugger?

Comment: Yes I'm using redux-devtools-extension

Comment: How do you add elements?

Comment: Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061935/react-redux-add-element-instead-of-replacing-state/69061975#69061975

Comment: 1. Reassign function parameter, as you do in map callback, is not a good style
2. Are you using two or more reducers for one item, or has your switch case statement just one action type for demo reasons?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fz7U1aEZ here is the complete action & reducer file

Comment: I found my mistake, I was wrote ...initialState instead of ...state in the SET_ELEMENT action. SIlly me

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping your elements array through a function that isn't returning anything when the id of the element doesn't match the action.payload.id.

Try this for your reducer:

```
const flow = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_ELEMENT:
        return {
            ...state,
            elements: state.elements.map((e) => e.id === action.payload.id ? {...e, options: action.payload.options} : e),
        };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's still have the same behavior

Comment: The error was not in this code, but I used your approach to refactor mine. Thank you!